Problems getting GPU working in Ubuntu
I built a new PC today and I'm hoping to use Ubuntu on it as the primary OS. I've installed Ubuntu 22.04 LTS. I'm having trouble getting my graphics card (an nvidia card) working properly. It displays images in the UEFI and the GRUB screen, so I know the hardware is fine, but as soon as I boot into Ubuntu, I don't get any graphics. The graphics card is attached via an HDMI cable. I've made sure the device is recognized (hwinfo --gfxcard shows both the motherboard's graphics and the dedicated GPU are registered, but the "primary display adapter" is the motherboard graphics device, not the nvidia GPU). I've also made sure to upgrade the drivers to the most recent stable version (nvidia driver version 535). When I run nvidia-settings at the terminal, I'm told, "nvidia-settings could not find the registry key file or the X server is not accessible. this file should have been installed along with this driver at /usr/share/nvidia/nvidia-application-profiles-key-documentation." I did have an existing nvidia-application-profiles-535.183.01-key-documentation file there, so I copied it to /usr/share/nvidia/nvidia-application-profiles-key-documentation, but I'm not sure that was the right thing to have done.
As requested by a helpful commenter, here is the output for a few relevant commmands:
~$ dpkg -l | grep libnvidia-gl
ii  libnvidia-gl-535:amd64                         535.183.01-0ubuntu0.24.04.1              amd64        NVIDIA OpenGL/GLX/EGL/GLES GLVND libraries and Vulkan ICD
 
~$ dkms status
~$

(dkms status did not generate any output)
Other potentially useful information - when I'm using the GPU to render graphics, the "tick rate" (for lack of a better term) in the GRUB menu is really slow, and often yields double inputs. There is no such problem when I use the onboard motherboard graphics.
Edit: I've learned the above "tick rate" problem is more of a GRUB bug with high-resolution displays.
Does anyone know how I can change the "primary display adapter" reported by hwinfo?
Does anyone have ideas about what I might be missing here?

Good point. I've added in the Ubuntu version I installed (22.04 LTS)

dpkg -l | grep libnvidia-gl and dkms status please [edit] your question for that please.
